# I have an inventory database in ASP.NET I want an error message if I try to decrease the stock by more than what is available

Tags: c#, asp.net, vbscript, sqlcommand, stock

I have a website based inventory system, I can increase my stock and decrease it. however when I decrease it I want an error if you try to decrease it to -1.

For example: I have 40 stock on one item and I want to take away 41 it should give me a error message saying `ERROR:NOT ENOUGH STOCK`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Inventory set stock = stock - '" 
        + txtstockremove.Text + "' where model_number='" + txtmodelno.Text + "'", con);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "Stock Successfully Removed!";
}
```

[Picture of negative stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb8gv.jpg)

Comment: You should never concatenate SQL queries with direct user input. This code is prone to [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), which could be a severe security flaw in your software.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest allowing the database to do what it does well.  Add a constraint to your `Inventory` table so you can guarantee that the `stock` really will never go negative.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Inventory ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Inventory_Stock CHECK (Stock >= 0)
```

The side effect of this is that your `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` statement may well throw an exception.  So you should really be prepared for that:

```
try {
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  GridView1.DataBind();
  Label1.Visible = true;
  Label1.Text = "Stock Successfully Removed!";
} catch (SqlException e) {
  Label1.Visible = true;
  Label1.Text = e.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to verify the stock before updating it:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select stock from Inventory, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here. You'll have to fill this part in

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (txtstockremove.Text <= currentStock)
    {


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Inventory set stock= stock - '" + txtstockremove.Text + "' where model_number='" + txtmodelno.Text + "'", con);


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Stock Successfully Removed!";
    }
    con.Close();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "Stock Successfully Removed!";

}
```

Comment: i will explain it better,  so i need a label to become visible stating "ERROR:NOT ENOUGH STOCK"  if i type 30 in the textbox and the stock available is 25. so instead of the stock going down to -5 i want a user validation error. hope this make more sense, sorry i am a beginner

Comment: Well, the idea stays pretty much the same as the code I wrote above. I would only change one thing: instead of connecting the function to ButtonClick, I would use the text box's TextChanged event.

So, basically:
1. Whenever the user changes the values - you test against the DB that you have enough stock.
2. If you do - no problem.
3. If you don't - display the error message (I would also disable the submit button).
4. If the user clicks the button - you don't need to verify again - just update the DB (same as you did before).

Hope this helps.